# make matlab's console scroll down

Tags: matlab, console, scroll

I am running a script that uses `fprintf` to print to the console. Sometimes the console stops scrolling down to the newest line printed and I need to manually pull down the scroll bar to see the last line, which is annoying because I want to view both the console and some figures that I am plotting at each iteration.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: In what situation does it not scroll? does something like disp(' ') make it scroll down?

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but do you add a '\n' to each line printed with fprintf? Matlab's console has some issues with very long lines being printed...

Comment: `for ii=1:1000,fprintf('___ %d\n',ii),pause(0.01),end` no problems in R2012a, the console is always displaying the last line.

Comment: @rody_o - my lines aren't very long, and I add a `\n` at the end

Comment: Any progress in solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The [following](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/10352) was posted to mathworks, might shed some light:

> The behavior of the Command Window in R2011a seems to have changed so
>   that it doesn't automatically scroll to the bottom on a line feed if
>   MATLAB is busy.
>
> If I run this in my shiny new MATLAB 7.12.0.635:
>
> clc, for a=1:100,fprintf('%i\n',a);pause(0.1);end
>
> ... the counter will just run down to the bottom of my CW and then
>   keep going while the vertical scroll bar grows. My dull ol' 7.11.0.584
>   (R2010b) and my linux version (either release) don't do that; there
>   the command window scrolls down on a line feed. Is that intentional
>   new behavior or a bug? If it is a feature, how do I control it?
>
> **Edit: Okay, I'm pretty sure it's a feature. If whatever is in the loop
>   isn't terribly computationally expensive and not calling system
>   commands or mex code, it actually lets me choose between freezing the
>   scrolling or letting it go by moving the scroll bar (i.e., if the
>   scroll bar is at the bottom, it updates as it used to). Seems like
>   this just doesn't always work.**
>
> Edit2: Also, that trick to control it only works on Windows 7.